# Locked filename

Tags: sql-server, file, ms-word, locking

I got a server with SQL, where i've stored a stored procedure which executes an .exe on the server. This exe starts a Microsoft Word doc and store some information and then saves it using filestream. The Word template update its progress to the db where the client gets the progress information.

Sometimes it crashes (don't know reason) and i've to log into server and kill the word process. Now to the funny part. After a crash the document name seems to be locked, I can't create anymore Word documents with this document. However it works if i rename it to e.g. template1.doc.

I've tried to find any process that may use this specific filename, but can't find it. I've tried softwares such as handle and processexplorer but can't find anything.
Anyone know what the cause to this problem is?

Answer (score 0):

If you set Windows Explorer on the server to show Hidden Files, you'll probably see a temp file created by Word. I must say, however, that using SQL Server to call an .exe (security risk on the server) which then spawns Word sounds like a very fragile architecture and prone to problems.

Comment: I've checked the temp files but there is none to be found. Even if I restart the server the problem still exists... I know that running word on server side is not recommended, however this is just a test to see if it works. Any other ideas?